# Meaning of the word "drill" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/cUojCUTKYlc). It is at around 6 minute and 3 second. Here is the context:

> I spend the next couple of days shadowing the dialogue over and over and **drilling** those flashcards.

I guess that the speaker means *repeat* by *drill* there, but I am in doubt because [the Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drill), which appears to me the most compehensive,
 dosn't provide the definition.

Comment: The speaker is creating a transitive verb **drill** which doesn't really exist in the sense  of learning by repetition when the device (e.g. flashcard) is the direct object. Usually the learner is the direct object.  *The substitute teacher drilled them on verb tenses.* Or the subject matter:  *The teacher drilled verb tenses all morning.* I suppose he's treating the flashcards as the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I spend the next couple of days shadowing the dialogue over and over and **drilling** those flashcards.

This definition of **drill** can be found in the Oxford Dictionary under drill 1, noun:

> 2.1 Intensive instruction or training in something, typically by means of repeated exercises.
>
> ‘tables can be mastered by drill and practice’
>   count noun ‘language-learning drills’

[drill - Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drill)

Although a noun, I believe this is an example of a noun spontaneously being used as a verb. In the context of self teaching or self study, it means to perform a drill (a repeated exercise) on or about something:

> Sally **drilled** the multiplication tables.
>
> = Sally did drills on the multiplication tables.
>
> = Sally did multiplication table drills.
>
> **Drill** the calculus problems so that you will do well on the exam.
>
> = Do drills on these calculus problems ...
>
> I **drilled** the flashcards.
>
> = I did drills on the flashcards.

*Drill* as a verb also appears in dictionaries, but with a different usage. Here, it used to mean that someone instructs someone else by means of a drill (a repeated exercise):

> 2.2 Instruct (someone) in something by the means of repeated exercises or practice.
>
> ‘I reacted instinctively because I had been drilled to do just that’

It is possible that the self-study sense of the verb *drill* (drilling multiplication tables, flashcard, and so on) was not common enough to warrant a separate dictionary entry.